# Can I use an interface to define allowable fields for an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

It's my understanding now that I can declare an interface like this:

```
interface IParams {
    success: bool;
    pk: string;
}
```

and a function like this:

```
function x () : IParam {
   var params = {
      success: true,
      pk: "xx"
   };
   return params;
}
```

This works fine but is there a way that I could do this and have the
params variable only accept values of success and pk? What I want is some way that will stop me from doing the following:

```
function x () : IParam {
   var params = {
      successssssssssssss: true,
      pk: "xx"
   };
   return params;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply putting a type annotation on the var declaration should do what you want:

```
var params : IParams = {
  success: true,
  pk: "xx"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
interface IParams 
{
    success: bool;
    pk: string;
}

function x () : IParams
{
   var params = {
      success: true,
      pk: "xx"
   };

   if ( params.success && params.pk)
     return params;
   else
     // handle exception
}
```

And then the code in the `x` function will only execute if `param` has two variables in it

Comment: The problem is that the information for what goes into params is determined inside the function x. There's a lot of logic inside there but for the purposes of this example I made it simple. What I need is a way to ensure that for example on line 200 of the function I don't accidentally write params.suuuucess = false;

Comment: But there is still no checking on params?  I can still type anything after the line "var params = {"  I would like to try and get type checking for params. THanks